# using %>% this, how to reduce the length?

Tags: r

I've been trying to reduce the length.
like that

```r
gapminder%>%
    filter(c(continent=="Kuwait"&"Saudi Arabia"&"Iraq"&"Iran"&"Korea, Rep."&"China"&"Japan"))%>%
    ggplot(aes(year,gdpPercap,col=country))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()
```

> Error in continent == "Kuwait" & "Saudi Arabia" :    오로지 숫자, 논리, 또는
>   복소수 유형에 대한 연산들만 가능합니다

```r
gapminder%>%
    filter(c(continent=="Kuwait"|"Saudi Arabia"|"Iraq"|"Iran"|"Korea, Rep."|"China"|"Japan"))%>%
    ggplot(aes(year,gdpPercap,col=country))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()
```

> Error in continent == "Kuwait" | "Saudi Arabia" :    오로지 숫자, 논리, 또는
>   복소수 유형에 대한 연산들만 가능합니다

```r
gapminder%>%
    filter(c(continent=="Kuwait","Saudi Arabia","Iraq","Iran","Korea, Rep.","China","Japan"))%>%
    ggplot(aes(year,gdpPercap,col=country))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()
```

> 에러: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

It didn't work at all. how can i reduce the length of this calculation as using `%>%` I need help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this if this what you want:

```
gapminder%>%
  filter(country %in% c("Kuwait","Saudi Arabia","Iraq","Iran","Korea, Rep.","China","Japan"))%>%
  ggplot(aes(year,gdpPercap,col=country))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]